# Unable to get the redirected URLs in Python. Tried using requests, urllib, urllib2, and mechanize

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

I have a huge list of URLs which redirect to different URLs.
I am supplying them in for loop from a list, and trying to print the redirected URLs

The first redirected URL prints fine. 
But from the second one - requests just stops giving me redirected URLs, and just prints the given URL

I tried implementing with `urllib`, `urllib2`, and `mechanize`.

They give the first redirected url fine, and then throws an error at second one and stops.

Can anyone please let me know why this is happening?

Below is the pseudo code/implementation:

```
for given_url in url_list:
    print ("Given URL: " + given_url)
    s = requests.Session()
    r = requests.get(given_url, allow_redirects=True)
    redirected_url = r.url
    print ("Redirected URL: " + redirected_url)
```

Output:

```
Given URL: www.xyz.com 
Redirected URL: www.123456789.com 
Given URL: www.abc.com 
Redirected URL: www.abc.com 
Given URL: www.pqr.com 
Redirected URL: www.pqr.com
```

Comment: Have you looked at `r.status_code` and `r.text`? Maybe the other sites don't like your `User-Agent` string - i.e. they don't want requests from bots.

Comment: When I used Mechanize - I tried br.set_handle_robots(False).

Comment: Please look at `r.status_code` and `r.text` to see if there is any message suggesting you a being blocked. `br.set_handle_robots(False)` simply instructs `mechanize` to ignore the site's `robots.txt`. It has no effect on whether the site will block you or not.

Comment: Just tried r.status_code and r.text. I get 400 and 401 messages

Comment: When I open them in browser - I can open all the redirected links at the same time in different tabs. I tried passing the cookie value too, no go. Is there any way to avoid that code 400 and 401. It is our API and we should have access. Not sure why I am getting that message after fetching first redirected URL

Answer (score 1):

Try a HEAD request, it won't follow redirects or download the entire body:

```
r = requests.head('http://www.google.com/')
print r.headers['Location']
```

Comment: I figured something out though. It seems like after requesting n number of times - I am getting the redirected URL. So I created a function (see below) and calling that function.

Comment: `code` def get_redirected_links(link):
  attempts =  # of attempts goes here
  while attempts:
    try:
      open_link = urllib2.urlopen(link)
      break
    except Exception as error:
      attempts -= 1
  return open_link.geturl()

Comment: So when I call the function with a given_url as argument, I get the same first redirected url for all the different given links. No 400 or 401 error, but I am getting the same redirected url.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you provided, but as you mentioned in the comments you are getting `HTTP 400` and `401` responses. `HTTP 401` means `Unauthorized`, which means the site is blocking you. `HTTP 400` means `Bad Request` which typically means the site doesn't understand your request, but it can also be returned when you are being blocked, which I suspect is the case on those too.

When I run your code for the ABC website I get redirected properly, which leads me to believe they are blocking your ip address for sending too many requests in a short period of time and/or for having no `User-Agent` set.

Since you mentioned you can open the links correctly in a browser, you can try setting your `User-Agent` string to match that of a browser, however this is not guaranteed to work since it is one of many parameters a site may use to detect whether you are a bot or not.

For example:

```
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I passed br.addheaders = [("Chrome/59.0")], and a cookie value when I used mechanize. I will try with requests and confirm.

Comment: Nope. Still the same. Is there a way to close the session or wait for sometime after fetching the first redirected URL and before I get the request for the next one?

Comment: If you're not using cookies then you don't need a session at all. And if all the `urls` are different domains then you don't care about how much time you wait in between. You should only be concerned about how frequently you request the same domain. But to wait between requests simply `import time` and put `time.sleep(n)` somewhere in your loop where `n` is the number of seconds you want to wait. This will only work after the server decides to unblock you, of course.

Comment: gotcha! I am trying something from below link. I'll let you know if it works. Not 100% sure, just wanna try. https://github.com/pgaref/HTTP_Request_Randomizer

Comment: it is randomizing ip and requesting but does not take a cookie value as parameter. seems like request to that redirected url definitely needs a cookie. Because I get this message **Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value**

Comment: Also, found http://willdrevo.com/using-a-proxy-with-a-randomized-user-agent-in-python-requests. Will try tomorrow and confirm. Thank you